# Create Lists and Tuples inside a Nested Dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to read a text file into a nested dictionary which further goes onto a tuple within a list.
The contents of the file look like this:

```
1976,A,001,58906,98257,002,66288,90069,003,106935,0,004,141490,34531,005,113553,0,006,69384,92113,007,110496,0
1976,B,000,34194,83722
1976,C,001,68404,96397,002,106054,71765,003,88854,79162,004,92435,93154
1976,D,001,116217,52565,002,144780,22819,003,0,1,004,1,0
1976,E,001,160477,56539,002,88829,121290,003,139779,52075,004,75844,75193,005,103746,64008,006,86493,35359,007,147064,45863,008,122342,68374,009,116398,44607,010,111992,38088,011,107618,62435,012,61526,130332,013,135291,63130,014,123285,46674,015,92735,35700,016,104545,91160,017,103898,54270,018,56683,101658,019,68722,124201,020,71193,146158,021,101837,44094,022,68543,114769,023,130619,86434,024,108296,51478,025,57966,17737,026,59093,112619,027,94988,114623,028,114612,28303,029,82515,10852,030,82767,28503,031,83155,0,032,92034,35394,033,77807,95398,034,100988,98147,035,87472,76765,036,90830,49368,037,49021,133634,038,103317,59092,039,86745,122657,040,102132,148512,041,94590,128784,042,103062,32565,043,93475,173576
.... and so, on..
```

I had to achieve an output like this:

```
{
    '1976': {'A': [VALUES("001", 58906, 98257),
                         VALUES("002", 66288, 90069),
                         VALUES("003", 106935, 0),
                         VALUES("004", 141490, 34531),
                        VALUES("005", 113553, 0),
                         VALUES("006", 69384, 92113),
                         VALUES("007", 110496, 0)],
            'B':   [VALUES("000", 34194, 83722)],
            'C':  [VALUES("001", 68404, 96397),
                         VALUES("002", 106054, 71765),
                         VALUES("003", 88854, 79162),
                         VALUES("004", 92435, 93154)],
            ...etc 
        }
```

The code that I have currently written is:

```
import csv
results = {}
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        list = line.split(",")
        year= str.strip(list[0])
        letter=str.strip(list[1])
        for x in range(2, (len(list))):
            value= str.strip(list[x])
            if year not in results:
                results.update({year: {letter: value}},)
            elif state not in results[year].keys():
                results[year].update({letter:value}) 
            else:
                results[year][letter]=[].append(value)
print(results)
```

The output which I get is:

```
{'1976': {'A': None, 'B': None, 'C': None...} and so on
```

I can't figure out why the lists are giving me none. If I try this : results[year].update({letter:(value})

Comment: try `for line in f:
        data = line.strip().split(",")
        year = data[0]
        letter = data[1]
        if year not in results:
            results[year] = {}
        if letter not in results[year]:
            results[year][letter] = []
        for i in range(2, len(data), 3):
            tup = (data[i], int(data[i+1]), int(data[i+2]))
            results[year][letter].append(tup)`

Comment: Thank you so much! That works. I believe my mistake was replacing the values constantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Expected and Achieved Output:**

```
{'1976': {'A': ['001', '58906', '98257', '002', '66288', '90069', '003', '106935', '0', '004', '141490', '34531', '005', '113553', '0', '006', '69384', '92113', '007', '110496', '0 1976', 'B', '000', '34194', '83722 1976', 'C', '001', '68404', '96397', '002', '106054', '71765', '003', '88854', '79162', '004', '92435', '93154 1976', 'D', '001', '116217', '52565', '002', '144780', '22819', '003', '0', '1', '004', '1', '0 1976', 'E', '001', '160477', '56539', '002', '88829', '121290', '003', '139779', '52075', '004', '75844', '75193', '005', '103746', '64008', '006', '86493', '35359', '007', '147064', '45863', '008', '122342', '68374', '009', '116398', '44607', '010', '111992', '38088', '011', '107618', '62435', '012', '61526', '130332', '013', '135291', '63130', '014', '123285', '46674', '015', '92735', '35700', '016', '104545', '91160', '017', '103898', '54270', '018', '56683', '101658', '019', '68722', '124201', '020', '71193', '146158', '021', '101837', '44094', '022', '68543', '114769', '023', '130619', '86434', '024', '108296', '51478', '025', '57966', '17737', '026', '59093', '112619', '027', '94988', '114623', '028', '114612', '28303', '029', '82515', '10852', '030', '82767', '28503', '031', '83155', '0', '032', '92034', '35394', '033', '77807', '95398', '034', '100988', '98147', '035', '87472', '76765', '036', '90830', '49368', '037', '49021', '133634', '038', '103317', '59092', '039', '86745', '122657', '040', '102132', '148512', '041', '94590', '128784', '042', '103062', '32565', '043', '93475', '173576']}}
```

I ran your code and the variable `state` in line 13 is not defined. Also, in the `else` block of the `if` statement, you are replacing the list that was previously stored in `results[year][letter]`. To fix this, just append the value directly to the list (don't create a new one) like so: `results[year][letter].append(value).`

**Working Code**

```
import csv

results = {}
with open("yearsandvalues.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        list = line.split(",")
        year = str.strip(list[0])
        letter = str.strip(list[1])
        for x in range(2, (len(list))):
            value = str.strip(list[x])
            if year not in results:
                results.update({year: {letter: [value]}},)
            elif letter not in results[year].keys():
                results[year].update({letter: [value]})
            else:
                results[year][letter].append(value)
print(results)
```